# Invoke a function in one Angularjs app from another app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

## tl;dr

I'd like to invoke a function (say `LOGIN()`) that is defined in one AngularJS app from another AngularJS app.

Is that possible? How?

## Long version

We have a JHIPSTER generated App ( lets call it as App1) which comes with Angularjs based Auth service.js along with REST API.

Now we want to be able to invoke those REST APi from one of our other App which is also based on Angularjs APP(completely different from the JHIPSTER generated one). Lets call this APP2.

So now to invoke those REST API the user must be authenticated by JHIPSTER's Authentication mechanism. So from App2 we need to login through JHIPSTER's authentication mechanism to be able to invoke the REST API.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What's your problem?

Comment: OK here is the full context. We have a JHIPSTER generated App ( lets call it as App1) which comes with Angularjs based Auth service.js along with REST API.  Now we want to be able to invoke those REST APi from one of our other App which is also based on Angularjs APP(completely different from the JHIPSTER generated one). Lets call this APP2.   So now to invoke those REST API the user must be authenticated by JHIPSTER's Authentication mechanism. So from App2 we need to login through JHIPSTER's authentication mechanism to be able to invoke the REST API.   HOpe its clear now.

Comment: The idea is to help you out with concise answers. The additional info helps but, without relevant snippets of code from App2, there can be only educated guesses. What error do you find when you try App2? Adding a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question will stop the negative votes and will give you answers. I edited your question but it's still too broad.

Answer (score 0):

We invoke functions in our own app after a page reload by passing the function and it's parameters in a request parameter, then evaluating that function in the current scope of the page.  We also pass a CSRF token to make sure you have access.